# What is the proper practice for managing local, remote, and upstream repos on GitHub?

Tags: git, opencart, fork, git-flow

EDIT - I've done some searching and believe I've found the answers to most of my questions, here is a summary of my findings, please confirm this is the best approach to take:

I'm planning to use Opencart to develop an E-Commerce system for my company.  Working with two to three other developers (sometimes in the office together, sometimes remotely), we will be doing lots of modifications to the Opencart source code (to tailor the code to meet our company's needs).  I plan to:

1. Download the Master Branch from Opencart as zipping and install it in a local Repo for development purposes.  I will then push that to Github for safekeeping as a backup AND as a central master repository.  In addition, we will use deploy hooks to deploy our code to our server when we merge/commit to the Master Branch then push to Github's (origin) Repo.

Note: I'm doing this because I'd like our repo to start clean without any of the 1000+ previous commits to the Opencart Project.

2. I'll set an additional "upstream" repo to port to the Opencart Project Repo on Github, so we can incorporate commits/fixes/new features/improvements made to the opencart project into our E-Commerce site in the future.

2a) Using the Git fetch - I'll pull commits from the Upstream repo.  Since the feature improvements (which may not be 100% complete when committed to the Opencart repo) and bug fixes/etc are committed onto the same master branch, can I use the Git cherry-pick feature to choose which commits to incorporate into our E-Commerce source and then disregard other commits that are for feature improvements (that we will incorporate at a later date when we know they are stable - typically with a future version release)?

Questions:

If/when we want to contribute back to the Opencart project since we WON'T be working on a fork, can I still submit pull requests?  Or do I need to set up a forked Repo in Github, then put the changes onto that repo I plan to submit, and then submit a pull request?

Is this process the best way to accomplish:

1. Ability to start with a clean commit history for our project (I think yes to this)
2. Keep our code proprietary and have the most control of making sure some of our proprietary modifications are not accidentally sent to the Opencart Project?
3. Be able to incorporate 'upstream' commits into our code as they happen?
   3a) Choose which/when to add 'upstream' commits into our code - since some commits on the Opencart Project are not 100% ready for prime time when they get committed?

Thanks so much for the help!

DS-Matt

---

### Original Question/s before editing post:

I'm new to programming/VCS and I'm getting started with GitHub.

I'm going to develop an E-Commerce site with two-three other programmers.  Since I'm not great with the command line I'll be using one of two GIT GUI's - Sourcetree or GitTower.  I'd like to use the Gitflow method for managing the project.  The E-Commerce site will be built using the Opencart Project as its foundation with myself as well as two other developers making modifications for our companies needs.

I'm looking for advice on how to properly manage our repos along with keeping up to date with the Opencart project. Here are the main questions I'm having:

1. Should I fork the Opencart Project as our main Origin Repo that all developers will pull/push to?  Or should we set up our own Repo that is not a fork of the Opencart Project?

**NOTE:** Most of the modifications we make to the Opencart code will be proprietary and we WOULD NOT want to share with the Project.

2. Some of the modifications we make we would like to give back to the Opencart project (if the Opencart developer would be willing to take our pull requests), we need to make sure these will work on the default Opencart code (without our proprietary modifications), would this change the answer to question 1?
3. Since the bug fixes in Opencart are NOT broken out into a different branch or merged into the version branches, but committed along with new features onto the Master Branch, is there a way to choose which commits get merged into each branch in my Forked repo when I pull commits from the upstream Repo?

**Example**

`Opencart Master` Branch (branch set up in my Repo to follow the Upstream Master Branch.

`DS Bugfixes` Branch (branch set up to merge the bug fixes from Opencart into our project.

When pulling all the commits from the Opencart master branch I can choose either to merge into The Opencart Master (for both bug fixes and new features) or merge into the DS Bugfixes, which would only be fixes I need to get into our E-Commerce code without putting the new features commits in.

4. Finally, how can I do these behaviors in either Sourcetree or GitTower?

I apologize If I'm using the wrong terms, I'm very new to Git and have tried to read tutorials but still need some help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't have the right picture about git yet.

`git` is an application for distributed control versioning, the *distributed* part means that you don't need a centralized infrastructure, if you need github for a special reason it's ok, but you don't need nothing more than your pc to work with x people and git.

In git you don't really fork, the closest thing to forking is:

- creating a new branch starting from the content of another one
- repositioning the HEAD of your branch
- having a branch that is nothing more than a pointer to another branch

http://git-scm.com/book
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDR433b0HJY

you should start from here.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your feedback.  I'm using github as a central repo for several reasons: 1) Safe storage/backup of source code (incase developers come/leave he project, computers crash/get stolen laptops are lost - we will still have a fully functional copy of the source code safe on github.  2) It allows for deployment automatically (we use deployhq.com) when we commit to the master to deploy to our live site.  3) it allows for big/issue tracking, provides a wiki for new developers, etc.